# Is there really a difference between the use of will and shall?

Tags: difference, american-english, british-english, australian-english, will-shall

> **Shall I open the door?**
>
> **Will I open the door?**

So far as I know , the first sentence means **will you allow me to open the door?**

The second question means **Will I have the ability to open the door?**
( it is not usually)used in the sense of seeking permission)

> **You shall do it**(obligation)
>
> **You will do it** ( prediction)

---

> **I shall do it**((intention- formal)
>
> **I will do it**( intention- more usual or common than I shall do it)

Do native speakers in all the countries follow the distinction between shall and will or does it change from country to country?

I am asking the question because some native speakers say that there is not much difference between will and shall and some say there is clearly a diference?

Comment: Note, I wouldn't describe the first question in terms of permission. "Shall I open the door" is more like "Do you want me to open the door?"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you answered your question correctly. *Shall* is asking permission, usually used more formally. A better way of translating it is: "Do you want me to open the door?"

"Will I open the door?" Sounds here like a rhetorical question. But it all depends mostly on the context of usage.

Comment: Although I respect and apply this convention myself, most of my (reasonably well educated) native English-speaking acquaintance are not aware of it. Don't expect the average English speaker to follow it in conversation. **Will we go to the movies tonight?** is as likely as **shall we go to the movies tonight?**.

Comment: @  RonaldSole.I agree with you because I said that there was not much difference between shall and will  with first person